# Detect system reboot from inside a service

Tags: android, android-service

Is it possible to detect when a service is stopped or destroyed by one of its own methods? e.g.
[onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onDestroy()) (not currently working)

What I need is to detect, from inside the service, whenever the device is rebooted or turned off.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` and `QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF` intents:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerOffReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Conversely you can listen for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent for when the phone is back on:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerOnReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Keep in mind the latter requires the device to be unlocked by the user first. In newer API, you can listen for `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` which will allow you to start your service or do whatever you need before the device is unlocked.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that, as I mentioned, I need to detect this from inside a service I already have, I assume that when you reboot your device, the service is stopped or destroyed, so I need to handle those events ,if possible, from inside my service.

Comment: You can handle them from the broadcast receiver